# Adobe air app running on background

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, background

I have an droid as3 app that i need it to work on the device background, i know that the android os is lowering the fps to 4 when it's on background which is fine by me, but, if i leave my app open and close my phone after around 30 minutes the app gets terminated automatically. does someone knows if there is something to do to keep it alive untill the user stop it?

i undestand that there is something i can do such as using the
executeInBackground() function or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I thought about was if there is a way to trigger a android service(to run on background) through Adobe air, and unfortunately adobe air cannot run as a service in the background or trigger a android service.

You may try to write an android service that runs things on background.

There is something I found [here](http://www.lorenzonuvoletta.com/create-an-air-ane-for-android-to-dispatch-background-tasks/) it may help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, i saw this post but i don't really know how to mess with eclipse and it will take me time to learn but i found a workaround. If you keep your app open and the phone gets shut on it's own it will still work untill the user will close it